# Add background music at specific time period in mp3 files using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3

I want to add background music after every 5 seconds in .mp3 file using ffmpeg.

I have 2 audio files : `input1.mp3` of 5 seconds and `input2.mp3` of 4 minutes 04 seconds. I want to add input1.mp3 after every 5 seconds in input2.mp3 like after 0,5,10,15,20,... seconds.

I am using :

ffmpeg -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=3 OUTPUT.mp3

The command is working properly. How can I repeat the input1.mp3 after every 5 seconds to input2.mp3 ?

Comment: These will help;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40221165/ffmpeg-mix-audio-and-video-of-different-length and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31941140/mp3-audio-merging-with-itsoffset-using-ffmpeg-no-effect/31957317#31957317